# Inserting data from EXCEL into a DB

Tags: excel, vba, macos

```
 ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim val As String
    val = Range("B5").Value


    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString

    Dim item As String
    item = "INSERT INTO [IndustrialComp].[dbo].[Header]("
    item = item & "  [server_name] "

    item = item & "  )Values("
    item = item & "  '" & val & "')"


    conn.Execute item
```

The above code inserts whatever vale is in B5 into a sql server 08 databse (industcomp) a table called header and a collumn named server_name.

I bascially want insert multiple values into this database..the three collumns are server_name, phys and virt.

e.g b5 insert into server_name....c5 insert into phys...d5 insert into virt.

Would I need to declare multiple strings or is there a way to basically list the values against the corrisponding collumns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way

```
'Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim val As String, val2 as string, val3 as string 
val = Range("B5").Value
val2 = Range("C5").Value
val3 = Range("D5").Value

' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString

Dim item As String
item = "INSERT INTO [IndustrialComp].[dbo].[Header]("
item = item & "  [server_name], [phys], [virt] "

item = item & "  )Values("
item = item & "  '" & val & "', '" & val2 & "', '" & val3 & "')"


conn.Execute item
```

This is fine if you are  in control of the input. If you are handing to a third party, be very careful of SQL injection.

A user could, for example, put the following in the B5 cell

','',''); DROP TABLE HEADER ; --

and you would be in trouble if the connection has rights.

Always sanitise user input in a situation like this and use parameterised SQL wherever possible.

Hope this helps.